# JavaFx audio file not playing

Tags: java, audio, media, javax

I have the following code. No sound is being played I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have a file called "Test" in the directory specified. It is of .mp3 format.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    Media sound = new Media("file:///C:/Users/name/Music/HQ/Test.mp3");
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Hello OP we need to know what the error is if any except of not playing...Something is wrong [either path or internally the file]

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS hey, there is no error. That's what is confusing me so much ):

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to play 4 min mp3 track on menu screen in my game. I've converted from mp3 to wav. Still nothing. Then I've tried shorter sound (1 sec gong sound)... and it worked! However the sound was like cut in the middle.
Well, that made me suspicious, so I've decided to **run this inside a Thread** and it worked! Then I've switched back to primary sound and now it was playing just fine.

For now I don't understand two things:

- why running this inside Thread helps
- why .wav works and .mp3 doesn't

It's not much for now but maybe it will help someone :) I will update my answer as soon as I find out!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `mediaPlayer.play();` somewhere.
`setAutoPlay()` only sets the autoPlay-property.

Answer (score 0):

1)If it is inside your project the .mp3 file in [`resources/music/test.mp3`]:

```
Media media = null;
try {
  media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/music/Test.mp3").toURI().toString());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2)If it is outside the project for example on `file:///C:/Users/name/Music/HQ/Test.mp3`

```
 Media media = null;
 try {
   media = new Media("file:C:/Users/name/Music/HQ/Test.mp3");
 } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Have a look on this question also : [Getting a mp3 file to play using javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347658/getting-a-mp3-file-to-play-using-javafx/41291987#41291987)

And [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) how it downloads the `Image` it will help you.

Comment: I tried what you are saying, in both cases, the program runs with no sound. I have checked "media" and it has the correct file selected as well as the correct file path. I have checked my sound, nothing is being played.

Comment: If it helps, when i use media.getDuration(), i get "UNKNOWN" as an output.

Comment: @ColonCapsDee The `Test.mp3` is playing well with Windows Media Player for example ? VLC will play it for sure even it is corrupted...

Comment: I dont have windows media player, i used VLC. I will download and check if it works on that.

Comment: Well I cant use Windows Media Player, but it works on numerous sound players (itunes, VLC, QuickTime Player etc

Comment: Ok, so I tested the same code out on my laptop (different PC). The sounds work, so is there something wrong with my Eclipse or PC?

Comment: @ColonCapsDee Same Java Version installed?