# Java: .mp3 audio file streaming from server to client gives UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: java, file, sockets, audio, streaming

So Im trying to stream an `.mp3` file in real time(like spotify) from server to client. The time i run the client i get `Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream`, i have seen many similar posts but i cant figure out what is wrong, im stuck for days. The example file im trying to receive from server named `AllDay.mp3` is 3.8 mb if this can help.

Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // play soundfile from server
        System.out.println("Client: reading from 127.0.0.1:6666");
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666)) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                play(in);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static synchronized void play(final InputStream in) throws Exception {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
        try (Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()) {
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(100); // given clip.drain a chance to start
            clip.drain();
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class AudioServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        File soundFile = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage\\AllDay.mp3");
        System.out.println("Streaming to client : " + soundFile);
        
        try (ServerSocket serverSocker = new ServerSocket(6666); 
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile)) {
            if (serverSocker.isBound()) {
                Socket client = serverSocker.accept();
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

                byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The AudioInputStream class does not support MP3.

Consider using JavaFX Media support.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html

[Getting a mp3 file to play using javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347658/getting-a-mp3-file-to-play-using-javafx)

Comment: thank you, i will use this for future functionalities, but for now i need to stream this mp3 file to my client in realtime. i have spent a month searching for it. can you please guide me?

Comment: If you are not going to use JavaFX, then you will have to add a library to decode the mp3 file prior to playback. Try searching on github for the terms "mp3" and "java". For example, https://github.com/delthas/JavaMP3 might work for you. There's also javazoom/jlayer I think it even exists on the maven repository.